# Error with utf-16 encoded data in python

Tags: python, unicode

Here's a snippet of code where a string is to be UTF-16 encoded and sent on the wire:

```
# -*- coding: utf8-*-

import unit_test_utils
import os
import sys

...
...
def run():
    test_dir = unit_test_utils.get_test_dir("test")

    try:
        file_name = u'débárquér.txt'
        open_req = createrequest.CreateRequest(factory)
        open_req.create_disp_ = defines.FILE_OPEN_IF
        open_req.file_name_ = '%s\\%s' % (test_dir, file_name)
        res = unit_test_utils.test_send(client, open_req)
        ....
        ....
    finally:
        client.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

When this is run, the error is as follows:

```
# python /root/python/tests/unicode_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/python/tests/unicode_test.py", line 47, in <module>
    run()
  File "/root/python/tests/unicode_test.py", line 29, in run
    res = unit_test_utils.test_send(client, open_req)
  File "/root/python/unit_test_utils.py", line 336, in test_send
    handle_class=handle_class)
  File "/root/python/unit_test_utils.py", line 321, in test_async_send
    test_handle_class(handle_class, expected_status))
  File "/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/client.py", line 220, in async_send
    return self._async_send(msg, function, handle_class, pdu_splits)
  File "/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/client.py", line 239, in _async_send
    data, handle = self._handle_request(msg, function, handle_class)
  File "/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/client.py", line 461, in _handle_request
    return handler(self, msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/client.py", line 473, in _common_request
    msg.encode(buf, smb_ver=2)
  File "/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/message.py", line 17, in encode
    new_offset = composite.Composite.encode(self, buf, offset, **kwargs)
  File "/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycifs/composite.py", line 36, in encode
    new_offset = self._encode(buf, offset, **kwargs)
  File "/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packets/createrequest.py", line 128, in _encode
    offset = self._file_name.encode(self._file_name_value(**kwargs), buf, offset, **kwargs)
  File "/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fields/unicode.py", line 76, in encode
    buf.append(_UTF16_ENC(value)[0])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is wrong with the code?

When I tried this exercise locally, things seemed fine:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 22 2015, 16:47:47)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> file_name = 'débárquér.txt'
>>> print type(file_name)
<type 'str'>
>>> utf16_filename = file_name.decode('utf8').encode('UTF-16LE')
>>> print type(utf16_filename)
<type 'str'>
>>> utf16_filename.decode('UTF-16LE')
u'd\xe9b\xe1rqu\xe9r.txt'
```

Comment: You passed `str` (py3: bytes) object to a function that expects `unicode`. Normally you'd pass `unicode` object and library will `encode` it into UTF-16. Here library got a `str`, tried to `encode` it, which string cannot do, so *tricky part* Python tried to `decode str->unicode` automatically, using default encoding `ascii`. If automagic were to succeed, the result would then be encoded to UTF-16. Here it failed.

Comment: Also, please check what `test_dir` is, it could be `str` or even mis-interpreted. That can happen if your `$HOME` contains characters outside ASCII.

Comment: Also, please check if newer version of `pycifs` is available. Your backtrace shows that it installed something as `site-packages/client.py` which is outright terrible!

Comment: a note: use `os.path.join()` to paste paths together, this function automatically uses the right separator

Comment: Required reading: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Unicode text, convert incoming byte strings to Unicode as soon as you can, work with Unicode text in the script, then convert back to byte strings as late as you can.

You've got a mix of byte strings in different encodings and the likely cause of trouble is this line:

```
open_req.file_name_ = '%s\\%s' % (test_dir, utf16_filename)
```

It is unclear what encoding `test_dir` is in, but the format string is an ASCII byte string, and `utf16_filename` is a UTF-16LE-encoded byte string.  The result will be a mix of encodings.

Instead, determine what `test_dir` is, decode it to Unicode (if it is not), and use Unicode strings everywhere.  Here's an example:

```
test_dir = unit_test_utils.get_test_dir("test")
# if not already Unicode, decode it...need to know encoding
test_dir = test_dir.decode(encoding)
file_name = u'débárquér.txt' # Unicode string!
open_req = createrequest.CreateRequest(factory)
open_req.create_disp_ = defines.FILE_OPEN_IF
# This would work...
# fullname = u'%s\\%s' % (test_dir, file_name)
# But better way to join is this...
fullname = os.path.join(test_dir,file_name)
# I assume UTF-16LE is required for "file_name_" at this point.
open_req.file_name_ = fullname.encode('utf-16le')
res = unit_test_utils.test_send(client, open_req)
```

Comment: The error I get is:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/python/tests/unicode_madhu.py", line 50, in <module>
    run()
  File "/root/python/tests/unicode_madhu.py", line 15, in run
    test_dir = test_dir.decode(encoding)
NameError: global name 'encoding' is not defined`

Comment: @maddy As my comment says, you need to know the encoding of `test_dir`.  I didn't define it since I'm not familiar with the library you are using.  It may already be Unicode and not need a decode at all.

Comment: I added `print type(test_dir)` to the code, and commented `test_dir = test_dir.decode(encoding)`, but the error this time is: `<type 'str'> File "/u/common/cifs/chroot/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycifs/smb2/packets/createrequest.py", line 128, in _encode
    offset = self._file_name.encode(self._file_name_value(**kwargs), buf, offset, **kwargs)
  File "/u/common/cifs/chroot/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycifs/fields/unicode.py", line 76, in encode buf.append(_UTF16_ENC(value)[0])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @Maddy, `test_dir` is a byte string.  It needs to be decoded to work with the rest of the code, but you commented that line out.  You can print the content of `test_dir` and guess the encoding, or use a library like `chardet` to guess for you.  `ascii` might be good enough.

Comment: I printed `test_dir` and added back the line `test_dir = test_dir.decode(ascii)`, and the output was: `<type 'str'>
test File "/u/common/cifs/chroot/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycifs/smb2/packets/createrequest.py", line 128, in _encode
    offset = self._file_name.encode(self._file_name_value(**kwargs), buf, offset, **kwargs)
  File "/u/common/cifs/chroot/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycifs/fields/unicode.py", line 76, in encode
    buf.append(_UTF16_ENC(value)[0])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: I printed the type of `open_req.file_name_` after `open_req.file_name_ = fullname.encode('utf-16le')`, and type was shown as `<type 'str'>`. Could this byte string with encoding as ascii be the problem? Did the encoding to `utf-16le` not happen?

Comment: Spoke too soon; the type of `open_req.file_name` being `str` seems correct. Could something else along the path be trying to interpret these bytes as ascii encoded?

Comment: @Maddy, It's hard to tell, but I think `file_name_` expects a Unicode string, not a UTF-16LE-encoded byte string.  Without a full example to reproduce the error, I'm only guessing here.  I'm assuming the `test_send` line throws this error?  If so remove `.encode('utf-16le')` and just pass `fullname` to `open_req.file_name`.

Comment: I figured out that there's another module which was doing the encoding, and it didn't like seeing encoded strings. Hence the errors. I changed the code to stop encoding and send the strings as is, and this works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Do not assign text to byte strings. In Python 2 that means you have to use unicode literals:

```
file_name = u'débárquér.txt'  # <-- unicode literal
utf16_filename = file_name.encode('UTF-16LE')
```

Then make sure you accurately declare the encoding of your source file.

Answer (score -1):

try to replace:

```
utf16_filename = file_name.decode('utf8').encode('UTF-16LE')
```

with

```
utf16_filename = unicode(file_name.decode('utf8')).encode('UTF-16LE')
```

Comment: @Maddy : I'm sorry that it didn't work - Can you try the "import sys..."?

Comment: This is the error I get: `File "/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fields/unicode.py", line 76, in encode
    buf.append(_UTF16_ENC(value)[0])
  File "/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: Don't do the `reload(sys)` hack.  [Why sys.setdefaultencoding will break code](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/).